# Applying distinct to single column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql query

```
select  distinct 
Process.ReportLogProcessID as [Process.ReportLogProcessID],
Process.ProcessTitle as [Process.ProcessTitle],
CAST(User0.PrimaryEmail AS nvarchar(max)) as [Process_Contacts.IsPrimaryContact]

  from
ReportProcess as Process inner join
ReportProcessContact as ReportProcessContact0 on
    ((ReportProcessContact0.SessionID = Process.SessionID)) left outer join
[User] as User0 on
    ((ReportProcessContact0.ReferenceID = User0.UserID)) left outer join
[Group] as Group0 on
    ((ReportProcessContact0.ReferenceID = Group0.GroupID and
ReportProcessContact0.ReferenceType = 2))

 order by
[Process.ProcessTitle] asc
```

and it give below result

[image]

if you see it returns two rows with the same 'Process Title'-'Testing123' is there any  way I can distinct this in spite of whatever be the 'Process Contact'.

Is there any way to distinct the result on the base of particular column?

Comment: So which `email` should it return then?

Comment: what ever be the email id, it should return only one row, either with a@a.com or b@b.co because both having same Process Title

Comment: And you don't care which? It is arbitrary?

Comment: because both email are associated to same Process Title, and I want it should return only one row

Comment: Then just use `TOP 1` and be done with it. It will only return 1 entry. The question is a bit weird, either way you take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query [Process_Contacts.IsPrimaryContact] column have different emails for both records. If you remove that column then only it will distinct records.

**UPDATE :** You can try like :

```
select  
       Process.ReportLogProcessID as [Process.ReportLogProcessID], 
       Process.ProcessTitle as [Process.ProcessTitle], 
       MAX(CAST(User0.PrimaryEmail AS nvarchar(max))) as [Process_Contacts.IsPrimaryContact] 
from ReportProcess as Process 
inner join ReportProcessContact as ReportProcessContact0 on 
      ((ReportProcessContact0.SessionID = Process.SessionID)) 
left outer join [User] as User0 on 
      ((ReportProcessContact0.ReferenceID = User0.UserID)) 
left outer join [Group] as Group0 on 
      ((ReportProcessContact0.ReferenceID = Group0.GroupID and 
      ReportProcessContact0.ReferenceType = 2)) 

group by Process.ReportLogProcessID, Process.ProcessTitle
order by [Process.ProcessTitle] asc
```

Comment: @BreakHead : Then you need to add group by clause and use any aggregate function to select any one email.

Comment: Thanks, any example to refer?